# open activity on Firebase notification received

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to open an activity automatically when a notification is received, it is working fine when app is in foreground but it is not working when app is in background.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewPickUpRequestActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TRIP_ID, tripId);
            Helper.setStringValue(KEY_LAST_TRIP_TRIP_ID, tripId);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Just ignore the intent when app is not in foreground?

Comment: Please add more code, this is just what you intended to do on a certain event, post the code that's related to the foreground/background operation as well

Comment: basically i am working on a taxi app. I am facing problem on driver side the scenario is when the user requests for ride the request goes to driver to accept or reject with a timer. When the app is on foreground it opens the activity but when it is in background or closed it only shows notification. it does not start activity even though I am using Wake lock in application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setClassName("com.your.package", "com.your.package.MainActivity");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

There are some exception you should consider when you will not be able to launch the activity https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: Another workaround would be using a pending intent.. 

PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, myIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).send(this,0,myIntent);

Comment: Solved Thank you.

Comment: "There are some exception you should consider when you will not be able to launch the activity" - in what situation _would_ you be able to launch the notification?  It should always be blocked unless you're doing something janky to dodge the restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

> There are two types of messages data messages and notification
> messages. Data   messages are handled here in onMessageReceived
> whether  the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are
> the type  traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only
> received  here in onMessageReceived when the app is in the foreground.
> When the  app is in the background an automatically generated
> notification is  displayed. When the user taps on the notification
> they are returned to  the app. Messages containing both notification
> and data payloads are  treated as notification messages. The Firebase
> console always sends  notification messages.

**Example code** :- You need to specify click_action in your notification payload like this

```
$noti = array
    (
    'icon' => 'new',
    'title' => 'title',
    'body' => 'new msg',
    'click_action' => 'open_NewPickUpRequestActivity'
);
```

Now in `manifest` file do this in your `NewPickUpRequestActivity` activity tag

```
<activity
           android:name=".NewPickUpRequestActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="open_NewPickUpRequestActivity" /> // should be same as in click action
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: The question asks to open an Activity when the notification is _received_, not when it's _clicked_.